# Replace accented characters using gsub

Tags: ruby, unicode

Here's my code:

```
text = File.read('/Users/username/Desktop/text.txt')
replace = text.gsub('hai', 'hǎi')
File.open('/Users/username/Desktop/text.txt', "w") {|file| file.puts replace}
```

I am trying to run this script from my terminal, but it gives this error:

```
XXXX:Desktop username$ ruby replace.rb
replace.rb:2: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
replace.rb:2: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
replace.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ')'
replace = text.gsub('hai', 'hǎi')
                               ^
```

I actually want to replace lots of characters with accented characters in my CSV file which will later be exported to my MySQL database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try putting `-Ku`

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby  -Ku

text = File.read('file')
replace = text.gsub('hai', 'hǎi')
File.open('file1', "w") {|file| file.puts replace}
```

Comment: `u` stands for unicode. I thought you have read :http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/the_kcode_variable_and_jcode_library

Comment: Now I got this error: `invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
 from replace.rb:4:in <main>` which is the `gsub` line.

Comment: well, i don't have this problem using your example. Time for an upgrade?

Comment: Sorry, I actually changed the line 4 to `replace = text.gsub('&#x41;', 'A')` which I think there is some characters to escape?

Comment: I actually tested with 1.8.7. there's no problem at my side.

Comment: Something must have not been good with my side - it works now, somehow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do these two links help? [Unicode strings in Ruby code](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/144111), [Bytes and characters in Ruby 1.8](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/bytes_and_characters_in_ruby_18)

You should probably also learn about [the basics of Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).