# Should I use hex ascii accented character code in HTML or use the actual character?

Tags: unicode, encoding, non-ascii-characters

I have several huge CSVs with lots of accented characters in html hex code: `&#xE9;` for `é` and lots of others, even `&#x2013;` for `–`, etc.

My site is a wiki for people to update listings. So when they are presented a textarea for update, the existing content is filled in, and obviously those hex codes will be shown.

Should I be bothered replacing those codes with actual accented characters, or just leave it as it is? I wrote a [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771189/replace-accented-characters-using-gsub) to replace the characters, but somehow the output are weird characters. Probably the format saved in Ruby isn't in UTF-8 format.

By default my site is in UTF-8, and the accented characters are displayed properly with some html coding in the view.

Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you clarify what the problem is?

If your data (CSV) is in UTF-8, and the default encoding of your site is UTF-8, then all you would need to do is make sure that when users are editing content, that content is properly treated as UTF-8.

You may not need to display the markup to the users. Perhaps you could leverage a WYSIWIG editor package like [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)?

Comment: Just trying to remove the hassle of replacing all the accented characters with real characters. I have seen many international websites that leave the hex code in their source. So I wonder if that's the best practice.

Comment: All things being equal, I would transform the data to UTF-8 (I assume that your CSV data are not UTF-8), side-stepping the need to transform user input at all. You would really only need to do this transform from hexadecimal character entity reference once.